# Question based on coding error, how to handle

Tags: support

I asked a question about asp.net.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037414/updates-parent-page-hidden-field-value-then-sent-to-client-for-evaluation

that was about an behavior of asp.net.  But I later discovered the problem was the result of a coding mistake I had made.

So, it was an incongruent question; i.e. made no sense as asked.

Someone added a comment, that was relevant and prompted me to discover my error, however, it did not answer the question.

I tried to answer the question with my report that I had made an error, but that was deleted by a moderator.

How should I close out this question?

Comment: Delete the question. Or just flag it as off-topic with the "cannot be reproduced / typographical error" flag

Comment: One option is to edit the question to show the code which had error, then write an actual answer containing the fix. If the error is some kind of "gotcha", and someone else might find your question and answer when they do the same mistake, then this would be good. But if the problem is just something trivial, then I'd just delete the question.